# How do I avoid overwrite in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have class called AlbumImage

```
class AlbumImage(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name="raters")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Album")
```

when i upload first image called (for example) image1.png  every thing in ok ,,,,
But if I upload another image with the same name(image1.png), and go back to the first object, I will find the second image in its place.

How do I avoid overwrite ?

Answer (score 0):

The `FileField` and `ImageField` will detect this, and will add a random part to avoid overwriting.

It is only if you set it to a string, that it will take that, since then you refer to the name of a file. But if you thus work through a (`Model`)Form, or the `ModelAdmin`, or you pass it with a `File` object.

Indeed, if you want to save twice an item named `3.jpeg`, it will generate:

```
/media/3.jpeg
/media/3_S12ggWF.jpeg
```

Comment: You are right, when I run the project on my pc, but when I use digitalochn space, it stores the image on the old name, and when I open the old image from django admin , the new image appears